# How to resize UIView properly when changing orientation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When I change orientation my textview resizes improperly, the bounds jump to the right or to the left or down or up... here is my code, help my please.... How can I resize my fullText UIView.. thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 { frameHor=CGRectMake(0,10,275,306);
    frameVer=CGRectMake(0, 51, 320, 351);
..
}



- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        //self.view = portraitView;
        [self changeTheViewToPortrait:YES andDuration:duration];

    }
    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        //self.view = landscapeView;
        [self changeTheViewToPortrait:NO andDuration:duration];
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- (void) changeTheViewToPortrait:(BOOL)portrait andDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];

    if(portrait){

        self.titleLabel.hidden=NO;
        self.backButton.hidden=NO;
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"det.png"]]];
        self.fullText.frame=CGRectMake(frameVer.origin.x, frameVer.origin.y, frameVer.size.width, frameVer.size.height);



    }
    else{   

        self.titleLabel.hidden=YES;
        self.backButton.hidden=YES;

        self.fullText.frame=CGRectMake(frameHor.origin.x, frameHor.origin.y, frameHor.size.width, frameHor.size.height);
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"T_iphoneauto.png"]]];




    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `autoresizingMask` property of your UIView. For example:

```
blackView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
                                 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
                                 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

From iOS documentation:

> Discussion
>   When a view’s bounds change, that view automatically resizes its subviews according to each subview’s autoresizing mask. You specify the value of this mask by combining the constants described in UIViewAutoresizing using the C bitwise OR operator. Combining these constants lets you specify which dimensions of the view should grow or shrink relative to the superview. The default value of this property is UIViewAutoresizingNone, which indicates that the view should not be resized at all.
>
> When more than one option along the same axis is set, the default behavior is to distribute the size difference proportionally among the flexible portions. The larger the flexible portion, relative to the other flexible portions, the more it is likely to grow. For example, suppose this property includes the UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth and UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin constants but does not include the UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin constant, thus indicating that the width of the view’s left margin is fixed but that the view’s width and right margin may change. Thus, the view appears anchored to the left side of its superview while both the view width and the gap to the right of the view increase.
>
> If the autoresizing behaviors do not offer the precise layout that you need for your views, you can use a custom container view and override its layoutSubviews method to position your subviews more precisely.

For more info look here: [UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I understand autoresizingMask tricks but when in Landscape I hide some views and should lift textview up... if I don't find anything better, I will stop at AutoResizingMask

Comment: You can change it's center property or just change frame, when you have another view mode.